# PySide2 Print Converting

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

How could I convert the printed statement into normal?
<PySide2.QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(0x1f00bde4c60) at 0x000001F012D3F488>

```
proxy = self.tree_view.model()
print(proxy)
```

Comment: "Normal"? There is no *normal* way of printing a model, especially if we the data structure and content types are unknown.

Comment: Okay, is there any way to see what is inside self.tree_view.model() by printing it.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand the problem, and you're looking for an easy solution, but since your question is too vague, we cannot give any. There are infinite ways of "printing" a model (assuming its content could be printed) not to mention that you're using a file system model, which is a 3d structure (complicating visualization even more) and is potentially dynamical and recursive. Please read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and try to clarify what you actually want to obtain, because right now your request is too broad and we cannot answer it.